# Next callback function in angular 7

Tags: angular, callback, angular5, angular7

As a beginner i was going through the difference between observables and promise, one says that once a subscriber is subscribed it can get a callback to its next method everytime data(Observable) is returned from the http request. I am unable to recreate such scenario wheredata is returned in streams and next is called multiple times, all i could  find is an array that is immediately returned as one data set. Can some one share such scenario where next() function is getting called multiple time for single request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

It depends on the `observe` option, which I forgot about in my original answer.

```js
Observable<Book> = httpClient.get<Book>('/api/books/1', {
  observe: 'body'     // Default
});
Observable<HttpResponse<Book>> = httpClient.get<Book>('/api/books/1', {
  observe: 'response'
});
Observable<HttpEvent<Book>> = httpClient.get<Book>('/api/books/1', {
  observe: 'events',
  reportProgress: true,
  responseType: 'json'
});
```

By default, `next()` is called with the response body, but you can change this using the `observe` option.

With `'response'`, Angular passes the whole response with status, headers, body etc. to `next()`. This is still happens at most once for each request.

With `'events'`, Angular informs you about several interesting events of the request-response exchange by passing a corresponding `HttpEvent` to `next()`.
For example, an `HttpSentEvent` indicates that the request has been sent completely. An `HttpHeaderResponse` has all the response headers, but no content.

If you also use `reportProgress: true`, your `next()` function will even receive `HttpProgressEvent`s which indicate how many bytes are uploaded or downloaded.

So when observing events, `next()` will be called multiple times indeed.

In my original answer below, I assume you observe the body.

**Original Answer**

As far as the resulting `Observable` of a HTTP request is concerned, you are right, each the `next()` function will be called at most once.

However, you can use several RxJS operators to transform the resulting `Observable` into another one whose `next()` function will be called more often.

A few examples:

```js
this.httpClient.get('/api/books/1').pipe(
  map(book => book.title),
  startWith('Initial value')
).subscribe({
  // Will be called twice: First with "Initial value", then with actual book title
  next: title => console.log(title)
});

this.httpClient.get('/api/books/1').pipe(
  repeat(3)  // Results in 3 requests
).subscribe({
  // Will be called 3 times, once for each request
  next: book => console.log(book)
});

// Suppose bookIdChanges is a Subject<number> that changes whenever
// the user selects another book
this.bookIdChanges.pipe(
  // Whenever the ID changes, the corresponding book is loaded from the server.
  // A previous request will be cancelled.
  switchMap(id => this.httpClient.get('/api/books/${id}'))
).subscribe({
  // Will be called whenever the ID changes, unless it changes again before
  // the response has arrived.
  next: book => console.log(book)
});
```

It might be ovious that `next()` is called multiple times here, if you know the operators involved.

But in a real project, HTTP requests usually are performed in service methods.
For instance, let's move the composition of `bookIdChanges` and the HTTP request from the last example into a service class:

```js
@Injectable()
export class BookService {

  private bookIdChanges = new Subject<number>();

  constructor(private: HttpClient) { }

  public selectAsCurrentBook(id: number): void {
    bookIdChanges.next(id);
  }

  public getCurrentBook(): Observable<Book> {
    return this.bookIdChanges.pipe(
      switchMap(id => this.httpClient.get<Book>('/api/books/${id}'))
    );
  }
}
```

Then we use it in a component like so:

```js
this.postsService.getCurrentBook().subscribe(book => {
  // ... do something with book
});
```

There are still multiple requests and multiple calls to `next()`, but now this is all hidden inside a service method.
This is a good thing, but you should make it clear in the name and/or the documentation of the service method.

The takeaway is that yes, a HTTP request returns an `Observable` that emits at most once, but if you are not subscribing to it directly, but rather to a transformed `Observable`, you lose this guarantee.